# In search of a necessary condition for completeness of some metric space with application to pde

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces, operator-theory

$A$ is an operator.

Consider a metric space $K$ (a function $f$ is in $K$ if and only if $Af$ is in $L^2$) where the metric between two functions $f$ and $g$ is defined as $\mu (f ,g) =  \int_{R^3} (Af - Ag)^2 dR^3 $

where $\int_{R^3} (Af)^2 dR^3$ and $\int_{R^3} (Ag)^2 dR^3$  are all finite

$A$ may be taken as a differential operator constructed from some PDE

A sufficient condition for completeness of  $K$ is that for every $x$ in $L^2$ there is a corresponding $h$ in $K$ such that  $Ah = x$.

Is there a necessary condition for the completeness of $K$ that is when is it true  that for any $f_{n+1} ,f_n$ in $K$ , and for the Cauchy sequence $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \int_{R^3} (Af_{n+1} – Af_n)^2 dR^3 =0 $ , there is a function $x \subseteq K$ such that 
$\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_{R^3} (Af_{n} – Ax)^2 dR^3 =0$ ?

The implications for this is that it will guarantee the existence of solutions for certain partial differential equations.

Comment: Is the operator $A$ linear?

Comment: yes you can take it to be linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that $K$ is a vector space and $A$ is linear and injective (this is needed anyway in order that you have a metric). Then, $K$ equipped with your metric (or, equivalently, with the corresponding norm) is complete if and only if the image of $A$ is dense in $L^2$.

In fact, $A \colon K \to \operatorname{image}(A)$ is a bijective isometry. Hence, $K$ is complete if and only if $\operatorname{image}(A)$ is complete if and only if $\operatorname{image}(A)$ is closed in $L^2$.

Comment: I found another sufficient condition : if the eigenvectors of A form a complete orthogonal set, then K is complete.